# How to get Validation Error Messages from Respect\Validation?

Tags: php, validation, respect-validation

I have been using [Respect Validation](https://github.com/Respect/Validation) for form Validation

```
$app->post('/', function () use ($app) {

    $validator  = v::key('name', v::string()->notEmpty())
                    ->key('email', v::email()->notEmpty())
                    ->key('message', v::string()->notEmpty());

    $errors = array();

    try{
        $validator->assert($_POST);
    } catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
        $errors = $e->findMessages(array(
            'notEmpty'     => '{{name}} is required',
            'email'        => '{{name}} must be a valid email'
        ));
    }

    if ($validator->validate($_POST)) {
        // do stuff

        $app->redirect('/');

    } else {

        $app->render('index.php', array('field_errors' => array_values($errors)));

    }
});
```

looping through `array_values($errors)` would give me:

```
"" is required
email must be a valid email
```

I need something like:

```
name is required
email must be a valid email
message is required
```

How should it be done using [Respect Validation](https://github.com/Respect/Validation)

Comment: I'm not positive, but I think this is related to a [known bug](https://github.com/Respect/Validation/issues/86).

Answer (score 4):

The messages are there but your `findMessages` lookup is searching for `notEmpty` and `email`.

What you actually have in `$errors` are :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => email must be a valid email
)
```

`$errors[0]` is your lookup for `notEmpty` which wasn't found.
`$errors[1]` is your lookup for `email` which was found.

If you change it to look for the fields in question `name`, `email` and `message`:

```
    $errors = $e->findMessages(array(
        'name'         => '{{name}} is required',
        'email'        => '{{name}} must be a valid email',
        'message'      => '{{name}} is required'
    ));
```

Then you will get the desired results :

```
Array
(
    [0] => name is required
    [1] => email must be a valid email
    [2] => message is required
)
```

Excuse the delayed response I purely stumbled on this by chance, you will find much quicker results if requesting support from the official [Respect\Validation issue tracker](https://github.com/Respect/Validation/issues) instead. This would also be the ideal platform for any suggestions you may have for improvements to help avoid the problems you've experienced. You will find the Respect team eager, friendly and always willing to help.

nJoy!

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer two above this is close. You just need to add an error message code block that includes the message as well as the name and email.

```
 $errors = $e->findMessages(array(
    'notEmpty'     => '{{name}} is required',
    'email'        => '{{email}} must be a valid email',
    'notEmpty'     => '{{message}} please enter a message'
));
```